# Converting text file encodings

Tags: command-line, character-encoding, conversion

I have been having a horrible time with text files that mostly have cp1252 encoding, but some don't. When I try to iterate over them in Python, I'll hit a file with some other weird encoding and the script will stop.

Is there any way to just globally use a bash command to change all the encodings in a directory to a standard encoding? I was looking at iconv, but could not figure out how to accomplish this. Thanks so much.

Comment: Useful reading: [blog post about Python 3 problems with unusual filenames](https://changelog.complete.org/archives/10053-the-incredible-disaster-of-python-3)

Comment: `iconv` can be used to convert files but you need to know what encoding you've started with. Does `file *` help at all?

Comment: I figured out that if I did an ignore errors, it worked. Thanks so much!